# Converting single image upload into multiple images upload?

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, upload

Starting a new thread for this particular issue...

Here is the code I have that works on my other site...it lets you upload 1 image:

```
  $photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

  //Writes the photo to the server
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) {

  //Tells you if its all ok
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
  }
  else {
  //Gives and error if its not
  echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
```

Here is the code I am using on my current site for uploading multiple images....not working at the moment.  Actually, in one section of the form, I am uploading a logo image, which is just one image.  Then further down in another section of the form, I am uploading multiple screenshots.  Not sure how to make the code work:

```
  //code for uploading multiple screenshots

  // check files are set or not
  if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

$errors= array();
$desired_dir="images/"; // replace with your directory name where you want to store images
// getting files array
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){

    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    // checking file size (because i use it)
}
    if($file_size > 8097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 8 MB'; // change or remove it
    }       

    $FILE_NAME=time().$FILE_NAME; // for creating unique file name
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        // moving files to destination
        $move=move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.$FILE_NAME);
        // you can direct write move_uploaded files method in bellow if condition
        if($move)
        {
            // inserting data into database
            mysql_query("INSERT into Colleges (`EMP_CODE`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES ('$codes','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type')"); // inserting data if file is moved
            echo "The file ".$FILE_NAME." has been uploaded"; // only for debugging
        }
        else{
            echo $FILE_NAME."is not uploaded"; // use this for debugging otherwise remove it
        }

    }
    else{
        echo $errors;
    }
        }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "All attachments are uploaded successfully"; // your success message/action
}

  //end of code for uploading multiple screenshots
```

What confuses me is that the SINGLE IMAGE UPLOAD code uses only ONE variable "photo" while the MULTIPLE IMAGE UPLOAD uses multiple variables.  The code is based on [this tutorial](http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL).  Not really sure how to get those 3 variables to work and it is a much longer code which confuses me even more.

So basically what I am asking is:How can I get a multiple image upload code to work, AND how can I get it to work with a single image upload code?

Comment: Where is your form data? how you are displaying in html?

Comment: If you search on here for "multiple image upload php" you get 1,139 results - have a look at those first

Comment: Where is your `<form></form>` ?

Comment: The html version of the form has a <form> tag.  This is the php file that processes the data submitted through the form.